# How to summing up the row values by passing condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to sum up the column (price) by passing sum limitation.
For example I have the below table and I want to limit the records by 10k or 15k.

```
ID      PRICE
x1      10,000
x2      20,000
x3      5,000
x4      7,500.00
```

I want the result should be

**For <=10000**

```
ID      PRICE
x1      10,000
```

**<=15000**

```
ID      PRICE
x1      10,000
x3      5,000
```

**<=14000**

```
ID      PRICE
x3      5,000
x4      7,500.00
```

I made some search on it.I find some window functions in postgresql i.e OVER function. so I written the below query

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT *, sum(price) OVER (order BY id) AS total
      FROM   test1
     )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  total <= amount
```

But condition <=15,000 and <=14000 not bringing the right result.

I want to sum up the price column and fetch the records which matches the sum result with our given amount or condition and more specifically it should return the records by verifying and returning any other record can accommodate within the amount which we pass

Please help me for it.

Thanks

Comment: The logic you want to implement is unclear.  Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you are trying to solve is a Knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem . It's NP-hard and it's extremely unlikely that any database implemented it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to sum up the price column and fetch the records which matches the sum result with our given amount or condition  and more specifically it should return the records by verifying and returning any other record can accomudate within the amount which we pass.

Comment: @Sandy . . . But there are many rows and combinations of rows that match all the conditions you specify.  You are choosing one of them.

Comment: So basically the database should give back the lowest number of record(s) in which it's is possible to stay below the sum up?...

Answer (score 2):

your Q is not clear but if you want you can sort the price column so you can get the minimum sum that is <= the limit.
try order by on price col:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT *, sum(price) OVER (order BY price) AS total
      FROM   test1
     )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  total <= amount
```

Comment: I want to sum up the price column and fetch the records which matches the sum result with our given amount or condition and more specifically it should return the records by verifying and returning any other record can accommodate within the amount which we pass

Comment: It is not that simple.

Comment: another solution is that using algorithm but it will take a long time.
such as backtracking or DB like Knapsack problem (dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

Play here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mckDPhtrY4vRrkF2NjhQcC/0

```
WITH b AS (
      SELECT *, sum(price) OVER (order BY price) AS total
      FROM   a
     )
SELECT *
FROM   b
WHERE  (total <= your_max OR price <= your_max) AND total >= your_min
```